# How could time move "slower" for some observer-A moving "faster" than another observer-B when velocity is relative?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, time-dilation, spacetime-dimensions

I've never understood how time dilation due to speed works.  Take the most well-known example of an astronaut orbiting around the earth at insane speed for a while and then returning to earth having aged slightly less than his earth-bound compatriots.  Wouldn't it be just as valid to say that the earth and the people on it were orbiting around the astronaut at insane speeds relative to him and thus they should be the ones who have aged less?

Furthermore, I'm trying very hard to understand the concept (as it has been described to me) that we are all moving at light speed in some 4-dimensional space, and that as we move through what we perceive as our 3-dimensional surroundings, we are actually just changing direction in the greater 4-dimensional space and what we consider time is just the dimension that is parallel to our direction of travel?  I must be understanding this concept wrong, or maybe I've been told some nonsense, as when I try to generalize this to a 2-dimensional space (1 dimension of time and 1 of perceived space/surroundings) so that I can sketch the trajectories of two observers on a piece of paper, I can't work out how time dilation makes sense as we supposedly observe it in the real world.

Any help with my understanding would be greatly appreciated, as even though I'm not a physicist in any real sense of the word, this question often keeps me up at night lol.

Comment: You have at least three distinct questions: the question in the title is about the reciprocity of time dilation, the question in the first paragraph is about the twin's paradox, and the question in the second paragraph is about four-velocity. Please focus on one question only, and each of these has a lot of previous questions here, so please read the previous questions and see if yours is already answered. If you find that one of these three questions is actually unanswered, please edit this to focus on the unanswered one, link to the previous questions, and explain what is still missing

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your question is a duplicate, so I will pen a brief answer before it is closed.

The key to understanding SR is that time dilation doesn't mean that time passes more slowly in one frame than it does in another- what it means is that the time difference between two events is actually shorter in one frame than it is in another.

If you are coasting relative to me, and your watch shows a time difference of 4s between two events, while in my frame the time difference is 5s, that means exactly what it says- the elapsed times are different. It is not that time has somehow slowed down for you, or that your watch has somehow been affected by your movement so that it under-reports time- in your frame the elapsed time really is 4s, and your watch properly records it as such, while in my frame the elapsed time is 5s.

You need to study the relativity of simultaneity, as that is key to understanding how the effect of time dilation can be symmetrical.

Time dilation occurs in SR if you move between two events that are in different places in my frame- the time you measure between the two events will be less than the time I will measure. Note that the set-up is not symmetrical- in your frame, the two events happen in the same place (ie where you happen to be), while in my frame they happen in two different places. If you reverse the set-up so, that I measure the elapsed time between two events at the same place in my frame, those events will be in two different places in your frame, and you will record a longer time between them.

Comment: I understand that according to SR time doesn't move more "slowly" per say, rather the elapsed time between events depends on your relative speed, that's why I put slower in quotes. What bothers me about every single explanation I've read is that they fail to address how time dilation could be non-symmetrical.  An example I was given was an observer moving away from earth and coming back near light speed, that two events that happened 1 hour apart on earth would have happened in much less time for the moving observer, BUT to him the EARTH would be moving away and coming back near light speed...

Comment: ...so wouldn't it be just as valid to assume that if the observer snapped his fingers once when the earth "left" and again when it "came back", if for the sake of argument the time that elapsed for him was one hour, than the time elapsed between those events for people on earth would have been much shorter?

Comment: @poopoopeepee123 in this particular comment you are asking about the well known twin paradox.  There is a lot written on this, and a lot of videos.  In my mind none of the answers are satisfactory, but they will give you an understanding of current thinking on the paradox.

Comment: @poopoopeepee123 The resolution to the twin paradox is that the set-up is not symmetrical. The travelling twin moves between two different reference frames (namely the outbound and return frames), while the Earthbound twin stays in one frame throughout. The difference in elapsed time experienced by the two twins can be entirely accounted for by the turn-round event, which only the travelling twin experiences.

Comment: @poopoopeepee123 You need to study the twin paradox to get to the bottom of it, but it makes complete sense once you learn how to think about it properly.